# Duplicate Text Messages, Verizon: DroidX2

Tags: sms, verizon

I have a DroidX2 on Verizon and I always get duplicate text messages and it's super annoying. Is there a simple way to fix this? Or is this a carrier issue?

Comment: are you only using the stock sms application?

Comment: Yes I'm only using the stock SMS app.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This does sound like a network (carrier) issue, however, do you have any applications that intercept text messages? If so, uninstall it, and see if that helps.

Edit: i just got this issue on an ICS rom. What i think it could be - your network holds the text, and tries to send it if your phone is turned off, or has no signal. It then tries to send them. After it has sent, the network doesn't actually realise it, and sends it again.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is clearly a carrier issue.

If you are using the stock sms application, I've never come across this apart from carrier forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a carrier issue, as said. However, this could be due to an issue with your connection?

You could possibly do a Factory Default Reset, and see if that alleviates the problem. Could be a faulty installation causing the connection to send twice or something? Not too sure how that works, but it might be worth a shot.

If not, then possibly contact your Carrier, regarding the issue, and they may have an appropriate answer for your query.

Answer (score 0):

My wife had the same problem on her phone and as the resident tech, it fell to mo to resolve it. She has a Blu VIVO XL V0030UU 16GB 4G LTE Unlocked GSM Phone. I tried disabling any apps on the phone that may have been receiving SMS texts and forwarding them on to no avail. Our carrier is Tmobile. What finally worked was going into the settings and disabling "Enhanced 4G LTE mode".

My working theory at this point is that the SMS is transmitted and times out waiting for an ACK and then resends.